# XCode5 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw with aiff file in debug mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-audio, avaudioplayer

libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw is throwing an exception when I use any AIFF file, any AVPlayer Jedi out there would help given the below trace?
Thanx in advance,

(lldb) bt
* thread #10: tid = 0x6346c9, 0x05fa5909 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw, stop reason = breakpoint 1.2

```
frame #0: 0x05fa5909 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw
frame #1: 0x02737d95 AudioToolbox`QueueAccessor::QueueAccessor(unsigned int, audit_token_t const*, bool) + 261
frame #2: 0x02733286 AudioToolbox`AQServer_GetPendingCallbackMessages + 134
frame #3: 0x02738613 AudioToolbox`ClientAudioQueue::FetchAndDeliverPendingCallbacks(unsigned int) + 211
frame #4: 0x0273883a AudioToolbox`AQCallbackReceiver_CallbackNotificationsAvailable + 122
frame #5: 0x026b1250 AudioToolbox`_XCallbackNotificationsAvailable + 64
frame #6: 0x027522e4 AudioToolbox`mshMIGPerform + 212
frame #7: 0x01a8edd5 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
frame #8: 0x01a8eb0b CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
frame #9: 0x01ab97ec CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2156
frame #10: 0x01ab8b33 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
frame #11: 0x01ab894b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #12: 0x0273fd10 AudioToolbox`GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 192
frame #13: 0x026f38d6 AudioToolbox`CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 150
frame #14: 0x0632c5b7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344
```

Comment: Did you figure out what was the problem? I have the same issue...

Comment: I never did, just set the symboling debugging break to objective-c